# Why do I need `sudo` to `make all`?

Tags: makefile

I am using hzeller's LED Library and this is one of the make file that I found:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter
OBJECTS=MP_Display.o
BINARIES=MP_Display

# RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION, this is where the library is checked out.
RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION=rpi-rgb-led-matrix
RGB_INCDIR=$(RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION)/include
RGB_LIBDIR=$(RGB_LIB_DISTRIBUTION)/lib
RGB_LIBRARY_NAME=rgbmatrix
RGB_LIBRARY=$(RGB_LIBDIR)/lib$(RGB_LIBRARY_NAME).a
LDFLAGS+=-L$(RGB_LIBDIR) -l$(RGB_LIBRARY_NAME) -lrt -lm -lpthread -lcurl

all : $(BINARIES)

$(RGB_LIBRARY): FORCE
    $(MAKE) -C $(RGB_LIBDIR)

Metrici_MP_Display: Metrici_MP_Display.o  $(RGB_LIBRARY)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Metrici_MP_Display.o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(MAGICK_LDFLAGS)

%.o : %.cc
    $(CXX) -I$(RGB_INCDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

Metrici_MP_Display.o : Metrici_MP_Display.cc
    $(CXX) -I$(RGB_INCDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) $(MAGICK_CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(BINARIES) $(OPTIONAL_OBJECTS) $(OPTIONAL_BINARIES)

FORCE:
.PHONY: FORCE
```

Why do I need to use `sudo make all` instead of `make all` to compile the code ?

I would like the resulting files to NOT be owned by root.

Comment: What happens when you try to do it without `sudo`?

Comment: I get Permission Denied erro.

Comment: Can you post the exact message, and the command that causes it?

Comment: Psychic debugging: the author of that library has a different permissions setup to you, and is writing somewhere they don't have to sudo for, but you do. Alternative: the author is so trained to sudo everything that they didn't care to check what needs permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you have run it as `sudo make ...` once, and it has created some files and directories that belong to `root`. Now you can neither overwrite nor delete them without `sudo`.

Run `sudo chown --recursive <your user>.<your group> *` in your project directory.

Comment: I've actually ran `sudo chown -R pi:pi /var/www/html` and made `pi` the owner, so that I can manipulate the files how I need. That solved it. I will change the owner to `www-data` as soon as I am done.